# TSQL subset supported in Windows Azure Data Services?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Windows Azure Data Services supports a subset of TSQL. What are the features of SQL 2008 not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336281.aspx